# RSpec test if method is being called inside a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

So, I have the following lines of code that I want to mock test with RSpec.

```rb
class BaseService
  MAX_BODY_SIZE = 100000.freeze

  def translate(body, language, account)
    return body if body.blank?

    translate_body_in_chunks(body, language, account) if body.size > MAX_BODY_SIZE
  end

  def translate_body_in_chunks(body, language, account)
    # some API call that I don't want to call while testing
  end
end
```

I want to test if `translate_body_in_chunks` is being called or not.

#### RSpec implementation so far

```rb
body = 'a' * 10000000
mock = double(described_class)
allow(mock).to receive(:translate).with(body, 'en', '')

expect(mock).to receive(:translate_body_in_chunks)
```

I know this test won't work. I just added it here to give you a hint on what I want to test.

Comment: Instead of a mock object, you can expect messages on an actual service object.

Comment: How do I do that? Can you help? I'm new to RSpec.

Comment: pretty much exactly as you do here, but use the real object: `service = BaseService.new; expect(service).to receive(:translate_body_in_chunks); service.translate(body, "en", "")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
describe BaseService do
  describe '#translate' do
    context 'with a body exceeding MAX_BODY_SIZE' do
      let(:body) { 'a' * (BaseService::MAX_BODY_SIZE + 1) }

      it 'calls translate_body_in_chunks' do
        expect(subject).to receive(:translate_body_in_chunks)

        subject.translate(body, 'en', '')
      end
    end
  end
end
```

[`subject`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-10/docs/subject/implicitly-defined-subject) refers to an instance created via `BaseService.new`.

Note that in general, you shouldn't test your method's *implementation* details. Instead, try to test the method's *behavior*.

Comment: This should accomplish the stated goal, but some would say that you shouldn't test private internals of object under test. Instead, verify outgoing messages (like that API call).